# What happens when an exception goes unhandled in a multithreaded C++11 program?

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, c++11, c++-faq

If I have a C++11 program running two threads, and one of them throws an unhandled exception, what happens? Will the entire program die a fiery death? Will the thread where the exception is thrown die alone (and if so, can I obtain the exception in this case)? Something else entirely?

Comment: Pretty sure the thread will die and you can't 'take care' of it without catching it inside that thread...but I think the other threads will continue. Would love to hear an authoritative answer though.

Comment: @sje397: I certainly would not bet that the process will survive. I wonder if with `exception_ptr` we can hope that the exception will propagate across threads, would be nice.

Comment: Seems I was wrong. Great question.

Comment: @Matthieu: An exception which is marshaled to another thread during a cross-thread call wouldn't be considered "unhandled", IMO.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Nothing has really changed.  The wording in n3290 is:

> If no matching handler is found,  the function `std::terminate()` is called

The behavior of `terminate` can be customized with `set_terminate`, but:

> *Required behavior*: A `terminate_handler` shall terminate execution of the program without returning to the caller.

So the program exits in such a case, other threads cannot continue running.

Comment: `std::exception_ptr` allows exceptions to be migrated from one thread to another, is this propagation automated so that the exception is thrown in the calling thread ? (Arguably, this could be difficult)

Comment: @Matthieu: That deserves a different question, this question asked about *unhandled* exceptions.  However, since threads run asynchronously to each other, it's hard to talk about a "calling thread".  Exceptions might be propagated when a different thread awaits the result of a task or future, however.  Section 30.6 starts out by saying "components that a C++ program can use to retrieve in one thread the result (value  or
exception) from a function that has run in the same thread or another thread."

Comment: @Ben: This is somehow avoiding the question, though: I mean, *where* can you legitimately catch an exception? Can you catch it outside the thread, like `std::thread t(f); try { t.run() } catch(...) { }`?

Comment: @Kerrek No you most definitely cannot catch an exception outside of its "thread or origin". The exception catching depends on stack unwinding, and stack is fundamentally thread-specific.

Comment: @Branko: I think that's the crux of the question! Thanks!

Comment: In C++03 (were threads are outside the standard) with pthreads. An exception in the main thread that is uncaught kills the application (as normal). But an exception in a child thread only kills that thread. I am surprised that this behavior is not what the new standard says should be implemented.

Comment: @Tux-D: C++03 also required an unhandled exception to result in `std::terminate`.

Comment: @Branko: With C++0x futures, exceptions definitely are supposed to be transferred along with the result.  This means that unwinding has to be done in the worker thread first (since the worker thread might even exit) and then the exception is transferred.

Comment: @Kerrek: Read section 30.6 which discusses "futures" and describes how results (including exceptions) are propagated.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the update, I wasn't aware of these new features. If it works anything like the .NET TPL, then exception is still not physically propagated outside of the thread - it is actually caught before thread exits and then "packaged" for consumption by other threads. Is this understanding correct or there is some additional "magic" taking place that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Branko: As I mentioned, unwinding has to occur on the thread where the task was executing, I assume this is done by "catching" the exception.  Then the exception is stored (there could be some packaging step) and retrieved when the future's result is inspected.  The standard describes observable behavior, it doesn't describe the magic that happens behind the scenes, and that magic often varies between compilers.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: As threads are not part of the C++03 standard that rule is not applicable to threaded code (as we are already beyond the confines of the standard). My question is really: why has the standard defined behavior that is so fart from what is expected (I would expect the thread to die (unless it was the main thread (then I expect terminate() to be called).

Comment: @Tux-D: Remember that pthreads started out as a group of cooperating processes.  On other operating systems, like Windows, threads have had kernel support from the beginning.  So the original behavior has always been to quit the faulting process.  It's only the new POSIX threads, wanting to emulate the behavior of the multi-process model, that allow other threads to survive.  Since one of the goals of the C++ standard is to describe a behavior that can be implemented on all OSes, there's really only one choice.

Comment: It's fairly easy to kill the other threads on POSIX, but how would you unkill the other threads on e.g. Win32?

Answer (score 33):

Since there seems to be legitimate interest in exception propagation and this is slightly at least somewhat relevant to the question, here's my suggestion: `std::thread` is to be considered an unsafe primitive to build e.g. higher level abstractions. They're *doubly* risky exception-wise: if an exception goes off inside the thread we just launched, everything blows up, as we've shown. But if an exception goes off in the thread that launched the `std::thread` we may potentially be in trouble because `std::thread`'s destructor requires that `*this` be either joined or detached (or equivalently, be *not-a-thread*). A violation of those requirements results in... a call to `std::terminate`!

A code map of the dangers of `std::thread`:

```
auto run = []
{
    // if an exception escapes here std::terminate is called
};
std::thread thread(run);

// notice that we do not detach the thread
// if an exception escapes here std::terminate is called

thread.join();
// end of scope
```

Of course, some may argue that if we simply `detach`ed every thread that we launch we're safe on that second point. The problem with that is that in some situations `join` is the most sensible thing to do. The 'naive' parallelization of quicksort for instance requires to wait until the subtasks have ended. In those situations `join` serves as a synchronization primitive (a rendez-vous).

Lucky for us, those higher level abstractions I mentioned do exist and come with the Standard Library. They are `std::async`, `std::future` as well as `std::packaged_task`, `std::promise` and `std::exception_ptr`. The equivalent, exception-safe version of the above:

```
auto run = []() -> T // T may be void as above
{
    // may throw
    return /* some T */;
};

auto launched = std::async(run);
// launched has type std::future<T>

// may throw here; nothing bad happens

// expression has type T and may throw
// will throw whatever was originally thrown in run
launched.get();
```

And in fact instead of calling `get` in the thread that called `async` you can instead pass the buck to another thread:

```
// only one call to get allowed per std::future<T> so
// this replaces the previous call to get
auto handle = [](std::future<T> future)
{
    // get either the value returned by run
    // or the exception it threw
    future.get();
};

// std::future is move-only
std::async(handle, std::move(launched));
// we didn't name and use the return of std::async
// because we don't have to
```

Comment: +1 Definitely agree with treating `std::thread` as an unsafe primitive.