# Exception propagation across threads?

Tags: multithreading, exception, c++11

In relation with [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7272093/147192).

C++11 adds the ability to marshall an exception to a different threads (using `std::exception_ptr`) and resumes its propagation.

I was wondering if such a propagation was automatic, that is: if I fail to handle an exception in a thread, is it automatically propagated in the parent thread ?

I somewhat doubt it (or it would have to wait explicitly for the `join` in some way), but I am not savvy on C++11 yet. Notably, I think that in the case of a `std::future`, it could store the exception automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Propagation is not automatic with `thread`.  If a thread throws, and that exception is not caught, the program terminates no matter what.

`future` and `shared_future` will store an uncaught exception in the child thread.  That exception is then automatically propagated when `get` is called.