# How to detect why thread exit on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I had a process with C++ on windows 2008R2, there are several theads in it. During the process's startup, there is a chance that one of the thread will exit. I didn't get a way to detect what happens, any suggestions?

Based on my investigation, the thread just exit without an exception. Access to a null pointer can cause the similar issue, but I didn't find such a position in the process. In fact, it should be better if the process just crash, then I can get a dump file; but nothing happens, just one thread exit.

I had tried the tool user mode process dumper, but it cannot work on the windows version that this process is working on.
I had tried the tool process monitor to check the thread exit event, but the process monitor will throw an exception when I try to reproduce this issue by starting the process again and again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Counterquestion: Do you think you would be able to write your own tool if no ready tool exists?

Comment: Can you add some code inside the thread function, that logs the entry and exit of this function?

Comment: Did you try starting your process over a debugger ? You should get threads exit code this way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272093/what-happens-when-an-exception-goes-unhandled-in-a-multithreaded-c11-program goes into detail about unhandled exceptions in a multithread program. The consensus was that the whole program terminates. That means that your thread may have somehow run through to the end and exited normally.

Comment: Sidebar: I did once find an odd situation in a multithreaded C# Windows Service where one thread was executing `Directory.GetFiles()`. Our network was a bit flaky at the time and in the middle of this call, the server with that directory on it dropped off the network. That thread stopped and never came back to life but the program and all the other threads kept going fine. It had exit logging logic but we didn't see this in the log. It was a production system so the Support guys wouldn't let us troubleshoot - they restarted the service and we couldn't reproduce.

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. Sorry for the late response. For the suggestions of adding logs, I had tried this before logging this ticket, but the position for the exit thread is random, the log will not help. When I tried to add more logs, this issue disappears. For starting the process with a debugger, I also tried it before, this issue just disappear. Based on current investigation, this issue happen with race condition, some debug ways cannot help.

Comment: For the suggestion from John D, the thread doesn't exit normally because the corresponding log is not logged.

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause at last -- the string is accessed by more than one threads, and one thread just exit. String is not thread safe.

Process Monitor helped to get the thread exit call stack on a powerful host, this makes the root cause clear.

Thanks all for your suggestions.